# Coupon Collecting Problem using Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: probability

I am very new to probability and combinatorics.
I am trying to solve Coupon Collection Problem using Inclusion-Exclusion formula.

I found a lot of references her a some:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

[Using Recursion to Solve Coupon Collector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287051/using-recursion-to-solve-coupon-collector)

but they all seem concern with expected time to collect all N coupons form what my problem is asking the following:

Suppose there are N coupons after buying n boxes what is the probability that at least one each type has been collected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the inclusion-exclusion principle as stated in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle): Given events $A_1,\ldots,A_N$, we are interested in the probability that at least one of them occurs. In your case, $A_i$ is the event that coupon $i$ never appears. The probability that you're after is $1-\Pr[A_1 \lor \cdots \lor A_N]$. It remains to find a formula for the probability that a set $S$ of coupons never appears, and to plug these probabilities into the inclusion-exclusion formula.

Comment: thanks. Suggestion with $1-P$ really helped.