# How many toys do I need to buy to get the whole set?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I'm collecting toys, they come in blind packs and there are 9 of them. Therefore for the first toy I have a 1.0 probability of getting a toy I haven't had before, then a 8/9, then a 7/9 and so on. On average, how many toys will I need to buy before I get the whole set?

Comment: This is known as the [Coupon Collector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem)

Comment: Also see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287051/using-recursion-to-solve-coupon-collector) and others on the site under coupon collector.