# Find the expected value and variance

Tags: probability

Determine the expected value ($\mathbb{E}[X]$) and variance of the number of times it is necessary to roll a dice until the result "1" ocurres 4 times in a row.

I know it is a negative binomial distribution, maybe with parameters 4 and 1/6, and I think $X_n:$ "amount of rolls to obtain $n$ consecutive 1s" could be the random variable.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I have changed this answer **significantly** because my original answer which was accepted was for a slightly different question and, not to mention, incorrect. I have (hopefully) fixed all errors.

Unfortunately, a negative binomial distribution is unlikely to be helpful here because it doesn’t account for the number of times “in a row” that an event occurs, only the total amount of times that it does. To take that into account, we treat this experiment as an absorbing Markov chain with transition matrix,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
5/6 & 1/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5/6 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 0 \\
5/6 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 \\
5/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The $(i,j)$-entry of this matrix tells us the probability that the next trial will put us in state $q_{j - 1}$ given that the current trial is in state $q_{i - 1}$ where
$$q_k = \begin{cases}
\text{“the current streak of $1$’s is $k$”}, & 0 \leq k \leq 3 \\
\text{“the current streak of $1$’s is $4$, or the experiment has ended”}, & k = 4
\end{cases}.$$
Now, the thing about state $q_4$ is that the experiment stops when we hit a streak of four $1$’s in a row; it’s a way of keeping track that we’ve hit the end of the experiment, i.e., $q_4$ is our absorbing state. The other entry probabilities are intuitive: at any step we could roll a $1$ with probability $1/6$, and that increases our streak by $1$, bringing us to next state; or we could not roll a $1$ with probability $5/6$, and that takes our streak back down to $0$. However, once we reach $q_4$ for the first time, the experiment is over and will remain in state $q_4$ with probability $1$.

It’s a standard result in probability theory that $\operatorname{E}(X) = \sum_{n\geq 0} P(X > n)$, and $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = \sum_{n\geq 0}(2n + 1) P(X > n)$ for any random variable, $X$, whose range is nonnegative integers.

One fact about absorbing Markov chains is that
$$
P(X > n) = \mathbf{p} A^n \mathbf{1}
$$
where $X$ is the number of steps until an absorbing state is reached, $\mathbf{p}$ is the probability row vector of the initial state with absorbing states removed, $A$ is the transition matrix with the rows and columns of any absorbing state removed, and $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of appropriate length whose entries are all $1$. In our case, $X$ is the number of trials until we hit four consecutive $1$’s (which is $q_4$), $\mathbf{p} = (1, 0, 0, 0)$ because our intitial state is $q_0$ (there is a streak of $0$ if the first trial has yet to happen), and $A$ is our transition matrix without the last row and column.

Hence,
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}(X) &= \mathbf{p} \sum_{n\geq 0} A^n \mathbf{1} \\
&= \mathbf{p} (I - A)^{-1} \mathbf{1} \\
&= \mathbf{p} \begin{pmatrix}6^4 & 6^3 & 6^2 & 6\\
6^4 - 6 & 6^3 & 6^2 & 6\\
6^4 - 6^2 & 6^3 - 6 & 6^2 & 6\\
6^4 - 6^3 & 6^3 - 6^2 & 6^2 - 6 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \mathbf{1}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} 6^4 & 6^3 & 6^2 & 6\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{1}\\
&= 6^4 + 6^3 + 6^2 + 6 \\
&= 1554,
\end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var} X &= \operatorname{E}(X^2) - \operatorname{E}(X)^2\\
&= \mathbf{p} \sum_{n\geq 0} (2n + 1) A^n \mathbf{1} - 1554^2 \\
&= \mathbf{p} \sum_{n\geq 0} ((2n + 2)A^n - A^n)\mathbf{1} - 1554^2 \\
&= 2\mathbf{p} \sum_{n\geq 0} (n + 1)A^n \mathbf{1} - \underbrace{\mathbf{p} \sum_{n\geq 0} A^n \mathbf{1}}_{=\operatorname{E}(X)} - 1554^2\\
&= 2\mathbf{p}(I - A)^{-2}\mathbf{1} - 1554 - 1554^2\\
&= (2 \cdot 6^8 + 4 \cdot 6^7 + 6 \cdot 6^6 + 8 \cdot 6^5) - 1554 - 1554^2\\
&= 2404650.
\end{align*}
$$

I have left out the calculation for the entries of $(I - A)^{-2}$ because it is quite tedious and doesn’t look as nice as $(I - A)^{-1}$ does, but any program (or human) that can do matrix operations will confirm the result. Note that I’ve used the fact that $\sum_{n\geq 0}A^n = (I - A)^{-1}$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0} (n + 1)A^n = (I - A)^{-2}$ for any matrix, $A$, whose spectral radius is less than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier and more elementary way to calculate the expectation and variance, by conditioning on the first occurrence of a non-1 face.

After a thourough search, I found that "drhab" already did the calculations for the general case, so all you have to do is just to plug in $N=4$ and $p=\frac{1}{6}$ in his second answere here: [variance of the number of coin toss to get N heads in row](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770235/variance-of-the-number-of-coin-toss-to-get-n-heads-in-row).

Yet another way is to calculate the generating function like in robjohn answer here: [Expected Number of Coin Tosses to Get Five Consecutive Heads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364038/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-to-get-five-consecutive-heads) and use its derivatives to calculate the desired mean and variance.

Yet another way (perhaps more intuitive) is to condition on the number of non-one rolls. If we denote by $T$ the occurence of a non-1 roll, then we can divide each sample in a (random) number of runs:

$$\underbrace{1\ldots 1T}_{\text{Run } \#1}\ \underbrace{1\ldots 1T}_{\text{Run } \#2}\ \cdots\ \underbrace{1\ldots 1T}_{\text{Run } \#N-1}\ \underbrace{1111}_{\text{Run} \#N}$$

Where the last run consists of for ones in a row, and the other $N-1$ runs are one of the $T$, $1T$, $11T$, or $111T$ (note that $N$ is also a random variable).

If we denote by $X_i$ the number of rolls of Run $\#i$, we can write:
$$X=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_{N-1}+X_N$$

Where $X_N=4$ and for $i<N$ we have $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables distributed as:

$$X_i=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ with probability }\frac{5\cdot 6^3}{6^4-1} \\
2 & \text{ with probability }\frac{5\cdot 6^2}{6^4-1} \\
3 & \text{ with probability }\frac{5\cdot 6}{6^4-1} \\
4 & \text{ with probability }\frac{5}{6^4-1}
\end{cases}$$

Therefore $E[X_i]=\frac{1550}{6^4-1}$, $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\frac{381750}{(6^4-1)^2}$, and:
$$X=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_{N-1}+4$$
Where $N\sim\operatorname{Geometric}\left(\frac{1}{6^4}\right)$ independent of $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_N$, so $E[N]=6^4$, $\operatorname{Var}(N)=6^4(6^4-1)$.

By conditioning on $N$:

$$E[X]=E[E[X|N]]=E[(N-1)E[X_1]+4]=(E[N]-1)E[X_1]+4=1550+4=1554$$

And:

$$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{Var}(E[X|N])+E[\operatorname{Var}(X|N)]=E[X_1]^2\cdot\operatorname{Var}(N)+\operatorname{Var}(X_1)\cdot(E[N]-1)=2404650$$

Comment: I knew the easier method for calculating $\operatorname{E}(X)$ by conditioning, but I assumed it would be difficult to do so for $\operatorname{E}(X^2)$ so instead I went for a Markov approach to calculate each moment. Using drhab’s method and solving $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = \sum_{n = 1}^4 \left(\operatorname{E}(X^2) + 2 (1554) n + n^2\right) (5/6) 1/6^{n - 1} + 4^2/6^4$ for $\operatorname{E}(X^2)$ does give the correct answer of $\operatorname{E}(X^2) = 4819566$. Amazing shortcut!