# Simplifying expression for expected number of coin tosses to get $h$ heads in a row

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, expected-value

$p$ is the probability of getting a Head. 
So the expected number of coin tosses before getting $h$ consecutive heads for the first time is:

$E(x) = hp^h + (1-p)[E(x)+1] + p(1-p)[E(x)+2] + p^2(1-p)[E(x)+3]+ ... + p^{h-1}(1-p)[E(x)+h]$ 
$E(x) = hp^h + (1-p)\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}p^i[E(x)+i+1]$ --------> (2)
$E(x) = (1-p^h)E(x)+\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}p^i$ --------> (3)
$E(x) = (1-p^h)E(x)+\frac{1-p^h}{1-p}$ --------> (4)
$E(x)=\frac{1-p^h}{p^h(1-p)}$ --------> (5)

I got this from the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376270/how-many-flips-of-a-fair-coin-does-it-take-until-you-get-n-heads-in-a-row). I dont understand how we get expression 3 from expression 2. Can someone please explain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: The coefficient of $E(x)$ is $(1-p)\sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} p^{i}$ and this is same as $1-p^{h}$ by the formula for a geometric sum. For the second term you will have to calculate $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} ip^{i}$. For this let $f(t)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} p^{i}t^{i}$. Then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} ip^{i}=f'(1)$. $f(t)$ is defined by a geometric sum with common ratio $pt$. Write down the value of this sum and differentiate to get that value of $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} ip^{i}$. The rest of the  calculation is straightforward.

Comment: I got the simplification after your hint but I used a different method to get the sum $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} ip^{i}$.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got the intuition for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-1} ip^{i}=f'(1)$

Comment: That is quite standard but there is also another standard method: the method if 'summation by parts'. Perhaps your method is something like summation by parts.