# Intuition behind odds/equation in Gambler's ruin

Tags: probability, markov-chains, intuition, gambling

A standard gambler's ruin markov chain set up is the following:
[image: Gambler's Ruin graph]

To find the probability $P_i$ that someone with \$i (i.e. at state i) will go up to state \$N *before* going to state $0$ (i.e. losing), we solve a recurrence $P_i = pP_{i-1} + qP_{i+1}$ and derive the solution using the standard methods in a textbook.

In these steps, we have the following equation:

> $$P_i=P_1 \left(1+\frac{q}{p}+\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{i-1}\right)$$

I was wondering, is there some sort of intuition for this equality? And perhaps more generally, is there some sort of intuition for what $\frac{q}{p}$ means in this context?

When I say intuition, I am thinking of something maybe similar to the answer in this post: [How many flips of a fair coin does it take until you get N heads in a row?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376270/how-many-flips-of-a-fair-coin-does-it-take-until-you-get-n-heads-in-a-row?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(Granted, the context is quite irrelevant to this. But you can interpret each term individually. Can you do the same here?)