# Derivation of formula for expected number of flips until k consecutive heads for any p

Tags: probability, expected-value

I was recently thinking of a general formula for the following question: what is the expected number of flips of a coin until you have seen k consecutive heads? What if the coin is biased?

While the question itself has mostly been answered, [I came across this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/455568) for the fair coin case, and I am wondering why it does not work for the biased coin case.

Specifically, following the logic in the answer given, for a biased coin with probability $p$ of heads: let $E_n$ be the expected number of flips until the $n$ consecutive heads. After $E_{n-1}$ flips, we have two cases for the next flip:

(1) with probability $p$ we get heads, and have $E_{n-1}+1$ flips 
(2) with probability $1-p$ we get tails, and have $E_{n-1} + 1 + E_{n}$ flips

This gives:

$$
E_n = p(E_{n-1}+1) + (1-p)(E_{n-1} + 1 + E_{n}) \\
E_n = pE_{n-1} + p + E_{n-1}+1+E_{n} - pE_{n-1}-p-pE_{n}\\
E_{n} = E_{n-1}+1+E_n-pE_n \\
\implies E_n =(\frac{1}{p})E_{n-1} + \frac{1}{p} \\
$$

Then define $f(n) = E_n + \frac{1}{p}$ with $f(0) = \frac{1}{p}$.
$$
f(n) = \frac{1}{p}f(n-1) \\
\implies f(n) = \frac{1}{p^{n+1}}
$$
So then $E_n = \frac{1}{p^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{p}(\frac{1}{p^n}-1)$

However, consider $p=0.25$. Then, according to the above for $n=1$, $E_1=12$ But by a geometric distribution, we clearly know that $E_1 = 4$. For $p=1/2$, this formula is correct, but for $p != 0.5$, this formula is incorrect (in the $p=0.25$ case, the formula is off by a factor of 3). Could someone explain why this is the case? Does anyone have any other intuitive explanations for the generalized formula?

Thank you

Comment: The correct formula for the generalization is derived in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376270/how-many-flips-of-a-fair-coin-does-it-take-until-you-get-n-heads-in-a-row).

Comment: Thank you. is there a specific reason why the derivation above in my question is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repair your approach, let $E_{n,k}$ be the expected number of flips needed to obtain $n$ consecutive heads, given $k$ heads in the current run.  The resulting recurrence is
$$E_{n,k}=p(1+E_{n,k+1})+(1-p)(1+E_{n,0})=1+pE_{n,k+1}+(1-p)E_{n,0},$$
with boundary condition $E_{n,n}=0$.  We want to compute $E_{n,0}$.